# MySQL - When shouldn't I Join tables? Combinatorial Explosion of values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cross-join

I am working on a database called `classicmodels`, which I found at: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx/

I realized that when I executed an `Inner Join` between 'payments' and 'orders' tables, a 'cartesian explosion' occurred. I understand that these two tables are not meant to be joined. However, I would like to know if it is possible to identify this just by looking at the relational schema or if I should check the tables one by one.

For instance, the `customer number '141'` appears `26` times in the 'orders table', which I found by using the following code:

```
SELECT
    customerNumber,
    COUNT(customerNumber) 
FROM
    orders
WHERE customerNumber=141
GROUP BY customerNumber;
```

And the same customer number (141) appears `13` times in the payments table:

```
SELECT
    customerNumber,
    COUNT(customerNumber)
FROM
    payments
WHERE customerNumber=141
GROUP BY customerNumber;
```

Finally, I executed an Inner Join between 'payments' and 'orders' tables, and selected only the rows with customer number '141'. MySQL returned `338 rows`, which is the result of `26*13`. So, my query is multiplying the number of times this 'customer n°' appears in 'orders' table by the number of times it appears in 'payments'.

```
SELECT
    o.customernumber,
    py.amount
FROM
    customers c
        JOIN
    orders o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber
        JOIN
    payments py ON c.customerNumber=py.customerNumber
WHERE o.customernumber=141;
```

My questions is the following:

1 ) Is there a way to look at the relational schema and identify if a Join can be executed (without generating a combinatorial explosion)? Or should I check table by table to understand how the relationship between them is?

- Important Note: I realized that there are two asterisks in the payments table's representation in the relational schema below. Maybe this means that this table has a composite primary key (customerNumber+checkNumber). The problem is that 'checkNumber' does not appear in any other table.

This is the database's relational schema provided by the 'MySQL Tutorial' website:

[image]

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: You are joining the two tables.  You are just using a key that is duplicated in each table.  It seems a shame that the payments don't have a corresponding order id, because trying to reconstruct one is . . . tricky.

Comment: 1.Can you clarify what you mean by "overestimate"? 2. It doesn't seem that there is meant to be any direct relationship between payments and orders; think of the customer as an account, and payments being made on the account rather than for the order, which looks to me like how the data designer was thinking.

Comment: @DonR Yes! I agree with you. These two tables were not meant to be joined. However, I would like to know if it's possible to check if tables can be properly joined just by looking at the relational schema. Or if I have to check table by table to analyze how the relationship between them work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Depending on the business rules there might very well not be a relation between payments and orders. Looks like the business operates on a monthly billing cycle, not a per order billing. Only thing missing is a Billing table to connect payments to orders and orders:orderDetails should be a 1:M not 1:1 as indicated by orderLineNumber.  With out it looks like you will need to process payments vs order details on a FIFO payment construction. Like @GordonLinoff said it'll get tricky. Further Customers:payments also should be 1:M. Generally the business  likes customers making many payments.

Comment: @Belayer True. I checked the relational schema again and the cardinality/ordinality of orders:orderdetails and customer:payments are wrong. I had not realized this when I created the post.

Comment: Any 2 tables can be joined on any condition. A DBMS implements in an order to minimize work from joins, ons, wheres, etc. FKs, PKs & other constraints are not for querying but for disallowing invalid states (&  optimization); they are facts true in every DB state. A table (base table or query (sub)expression) & its value represent a relationship/association; the value is the tuples satisfying the relationship/association. A query expresses desired ones in terms of base ones. You need sufficient tables to record what you want to know. (FK constraints are wrongly called relationships.)

Comment: @DonR I changed 'overestimation' to 'combinatorial/cartesian explosion', as informed by the other users. Now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "combinatorial explosion" and it happens when rows in one table each join to multiple rows in other tables.

(It's not "overestimation" or any sort of estimation. It's counting data items multiple times when it should only count them once.)

It's a notorious pitfall of summarizing data in one-to-many relationships. In your example each customer may have no orders, one order, or more than one. Independently, they may have no payments, one, or many.

The trick is this:  Use subqueries so your toplevel query with GROUP BY avoids joining one-to-many relationships serially.  In the query you showed us, that's happening.

You can this subquery to get a resultset with just one row per customer. (try it.)

```sql
                    SELECT customernumber, 
                           SUM(amount) amount
                      FROM payments 
                  GROUP BY customernumber
```

Likewise you can get the value of all orders for each customer with this

```sql
                    SELECT c.customernumber, 
                           SUM(od.qytOrdered * od.priceEach) amount
                      FROM orders o
                      JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
                     GROUP BY c.customernumber
```

This JOIN won't explode in your face because customer can have multiple orders, and each order can have multiple details. So it's a strict hierarchical rollup.

Now, we can use these subqueries in the main query.

```sql
SELECT c.customernumber, p.payments, o.orders 
  FROM customers c
  LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT c.customernumber, 
                           SUM(od.qytOrdered * od.priceEach) orders
                      FROM orders o
                      JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
                     GROUP BY c.customernumber
            ) o ON c.customernumber = o.customernumber
  LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT customernumber, 
                           SUM() payment
                      FROM payments 
                  GROUP BY customernumber
            ) p on c.customernumber = p.customernumber
```

Takehome tricks:

1. A subquery IS a table (a virtual table) that can be used whereever you might mention a table or a view.
2. The GROUP BY stuff in this query happens separately in two subqueries, so no combinatorial explosions.
3. All three participants in the toplevel JOIN have either one or zero rows per `customernumber`.
4. The LEFT JOINs are there so we can still see customers with (importantly for a business) no orders or no payments. With the ordinary inner JOIN, rows have to match both sides of the ON conditions or they're omitted from the resultset.

**Pro tip** Format your SQL queries fanatically carefully: They are really verbose. Adm. Grace Hopper would be proud. That means they get quite long and nested, putting the *Structured* in Structured Query Language. If you, or anybody, is going to reason about them in future, we *must* be able to grasp the structure easily.

**Pro tip 2** The data engineer who designed this database did a really good job thinking it through and documenting it. Aspire to this level of quality. (Rarely reached in the real world.)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! It is very clear! By any chance, do you know why some tables have two asterisks (orderdetails and payments)?  I thought they represented composite primary keys, but this wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @marcos-analyst They represent composite primary keys. Why do you think it doesn't make sense? (Take a read of my answer, it might help explain it)

Comment: `orderdetails` does indeed have a composite PK. That means any order can have at most line item ( one detail row) for any given `productCode`. So this composite PK implicitly enforces a business rule. That's fine, as long as the small and large StackOverflow-logo T-shirts you're selling have different product codes. But if somebody decided to add a  `productSize` column to `orderdetails`, confusion would ensue the first time a customer  ordered both a large and a small.

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for your answer! I said this because as they are composite primary keys, shouldn't it be prohibited for us to join tables by using just a fraction of the composite key?

Comment: Certainly not! Nothing prohibits joining tables on any columns. The purpose of primary keys (PK) is to provide a way of looking up guaranteed-exactly one row in a table. Sometimes PKs are autoincrementing id numbers, and other times they're composites like this one. The purpose of foreign keys (FK) is to enforce rules about relationship. `orderdetails` could use its `orderNumber` column as an FK  to `orders`. If that were set up it would be impossible to INSERT an orphan `orderdetails` row, with no corresponding `orders` row. But it's possible to join on columns that aren't either PKs or FKs.

Comment: @O.Jones Understood! Thank you ! I added an answer to this post based on your reply. Please, check it out in case you want to see it.

Comment: Two tables can be joined by anything; it matters not about primary keys or foreign keys. They don't even have to exist. You don't even have to join on anything to do with a table. `SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON DAY(NOW()) = 'Monday'` will join every row in a to every row in b, but only if it's Monday. Think of joins as working like "every row in a is joined to every row in b, then the result set is scanned and every row is tested against the set of truths presented in the ON. If overall they evaluate to true the row appears in the result set" - keys are wholly irrelevant to this process

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, your behavior should depend on the accounting style being supported by the database, and this does not appear to be "open item" style accounting ie when an order is raised for 1000 there does not need to be a payment against it for 1000.. This is perhaps unusual in most consumer experience because you will be quite familiar with open item style ordering from Amazon - you buy a 500 dollar tv and a 500 dollar games console, the order is a thousand dollars and you pay for it, the payment going against the order. However, you're also familiar with "balance forward" accounting if you paid for that order using your credit card because you make similar purchases every day for a month and hen you get a statement from your bank saying you owe 31000 and you pay a lump of money, doesn't even have to be 31k. You aren't expected to make 31 payments of 1000 to your bank at the end of the month. Your bank allocate it to the oldest items on the account (if they're nice, or the newest items if they're not) and may eventually charge you interest on unpaid transactions

> 1 ) Is there a way to look at the relational schema and identify if a Join can be executed

Yes, you can tell looking at the schema- customer has many orders, customer makes many payments, but there is no relation between the order and payment tables at all so we can see there is no attempt to directly attach a payment to an order. You can see that customer is a parent table of payment and order, and therefore enjoys a relationship with each of them but they do not relate to each other. If you had Person, Car and Address tables, a person has many addresses during their life, and many cars but it doesn't mean there is a relationship between cars and addresses

In such a case it simply doesn't make sense to join `payments to customers to orders` because they do not relate that way. If you want to make such a join and not suffer a Cartesian explosion then you absolutely have to sum one side or the other (or both) to ensure that your joins are 1:1 and 1:M (or 1:1 and 1:1). You cannot arrange a join that is a pair of 1:M.

Going back to the car/person/address example to make any meaningful joins, you have to build more information into the question and arrange the join to create the answer. Perhaps the question is "what cars did they own while they lived at" - this flattens the Person:Address relationship to 1:1 but leaves Person:Car as 1:M so they might have owned many cars during their time in that house. "What was the newest car they owned while living at..." might be 1:1 on both sides if there is a clear winner for "newest" (though if they bought two cars manufactured at identical times...)

Which side you sum in your orders case will depend on what you want to know, but in this case I'd say you usually want to know "which orders haven't been paid for" and that's summing all payments and rolling summing all orders then looking at what point the rolling sum exceeds the sum of payments.. those are the unpaid orders

Take a look again at your *database* graph (the one that was present in the first iteration of your question). See the lines between tables have 3 angled legs on one end - that's the many end. You can start at any table in the graph and join to other tables by walking along the relationship. If you're going from the many end to the one end, and assuming you've picked out a single row in the start table (a single order) you can always walk to any other table in the many->one direction and not increase your row count. If you walk the other way you potentially increase your row count. If you split and walk two ways that both increase row count you get a Cartesian explosion. Of course, also you don't have to only join on relation lines, but that's out of scope for the question

ps: this is easier to see on the db diagram than the ERD in the question because the database purely concerns itself with the columns that are foreign keyed. The ERD is saying a customer has zero or one payments with a particular check number but the database will only be concerned with "the customer ID appears once in the customer table and multiple times in the payment table" because only part of the compound primary key of payment is keyed to the customer table. In other words, the ERD is concerned with business logic relations too, but the db diagram is purely how tables relate and they aren't necessarily aligned. For this reason the db diagrams are probably easier to read when walking round for join strategies

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! I added an answer to this post based on the question that you proposed, which allows us to identify "which orders haven't been paid" by the customers. As you said, this creates a pertinent reason to join 'orders', 'payments' and 'customers' tables. Please, check it out in case you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the answers of Caius Jard and O.Jones (please, check their replies), which kindly helped me to clarify this doubt, I decided to create a table to identify which customers paid for all orders they made and which ones did not. This creates a pertinent reason to join 'orders', 'orderdetails', 'payments' and 'customers' tables, because some orders may have been cancelled or still may be 'On Hold', as we can see in their corresponding 'status' in the 'orders' table. Also, this enables us to execute this join without generating a 'combinatorial explosion'.

I did this by using the `CASE statement`, which registers when `py.amount` and `amount_in_orders` match, don't match or when they are NULL (customers which did not make orders or payments):

```
SELECT
    c.customerNumber, 
    py.amount, 
    amount_in_orders,
    CASE
        WHEN py.amount=amount_in_orders THEN 'Match'
        WHEN py.amount IS NULL AND amount_in_orders IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
        ELSE 'Don''t Match'
    END AS Match
FROM
    customers c

    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT
            o.customerNumber, SUM(od.quantityOrdered*od.priceEach) AS amount_in_orders
        FROM
            orders o
            JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderNumber=od.orderNumber
        GROUP BY o.customerNumber
    ) o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber

    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT customernumber, SUM(amount) AS amount
        FROM payments
        GROUP BY customerNumber
    ) py ON c.customerNumber=py.customerNumber
ORDER BY py.amount DESC;
```

The query returned 122 rows. The images below are fractions of the generated output, so you can visualize what happened:

[image]

For instance, we can see that the customers identified by the numbers '141', '124', '119' and '496' did not pay for all the orders they made. Maybe some of them where cancelled or maybe they simply did not pay for them yet.

And this image shows some of the columns (not all of them) that are NULL:

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of reformatting your SQL; when you make subqueries you should strive to use indentation to clearly indicate the "subquery level" - don't put all your SQL block keywords (SELECT, CASE, FROM, GROUP, ORDER etc) from all your queries (sub or main level)  at the start of the line; if you do, then the only thing that visually denotes the end of a subquery is its closing parenthesis and they were very hard to see. I recommend at least putting the closing paren on its own line.For subqueries that pull only few columns from one table, put identifiers and keywords on the same line